# Trying to create maintainable custom XML C# Class Serialization (Will be used in AWS Lambda project)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, aws-lambda, deserialization

We are trying to develop a class library to interface with a service that provides each function as a web service endpoint (we will be using about 200-300 of these, perhaps more). We will be using AWS Lambda as a proxy between this and other services.

While WSDL are available, the amount of code that is generated through "Add Service Reference" is massive (will generate 250,000+ lines of code, could be more), and the element names can be cryptic and are all caps. These classes will also have several subclasses and enums due to XML enumerations (each class added will have an enum that is 1700 items)

I want to avoid this bloat, so I was looking at custom classes and custom serialization. I wanted to come up with a generalized serialization methodology to avoid what seems like an obvious pit fall of individual class serializers.

I've looked at custom attributes, and this could work, but there are some complexities.

First, there are choice elements in the XSD that need to be addressed, as well as nested elements, as an example

```
<xs:element name="CODEDESCFIELD">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="CODEVALUE"/>
      <xs:element ref="DESCRIPTION" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and, with attributes

```
<xs:element name="ENTITYCODEFIELD">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="CODEVALUE"/>
      <xs:element ref="DESCRIPTION" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

as well as stuff like

```
<xs:complexType name="DATETIME">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="of:YEAR"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:MONTH"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:DAY"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:HOUR"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:MINUTE"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:SECOND"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:SUBSECOND"/>
    <xs:element ref="of:TIMEZONE"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="qualifier" type="DATETIMEqual" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="DATETIMEqual">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="ACCOUNTING"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="ACTEND"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="ACTSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="APPREQ"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="APPROVAL"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="AVAILABLE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BKTEND"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BKTSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CANCEL"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CHANGEDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="COMPDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CONSUME"/>           
    <xs:enumeration value="CREATION"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CUMULATIVE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="DELIVACT"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="DELIVSCHED"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="DISCNT"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="DOCUMENT"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="DUE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EARLSTEFF"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EARLSTSHIP"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EFFECTIVE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="ENGCHG"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EXECFINISH"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EXECSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EXPIRATION"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FAILDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FORECASTF"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FORECASTS"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="FROM"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="GENERATION"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="JOBDUE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="IMPL"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="INVOICE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="LABORFINSH"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="LABORSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="LASTUSED"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="LOADING"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="MATCHING"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="MSMENTDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="NEEDDELV"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="OPFINISH"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="OPSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PAYEND"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PLANEND"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PLANSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PO"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PROMDELV"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PROMSHIP"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="PYMTTERM"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RECEIVED"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="REPORTDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="REPORTNGFN"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="REPORTNGST"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="REQUIRED"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RESORCDWNF"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RESORCDWNS"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RSPDDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RSPDOCGEN"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SCHEND"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SCHSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SETUPFINSH"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SETUPSTART"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SHIP"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="SHIPSCHED"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="STATUSDATE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="TEARDOWNF"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="TEARDOWNS"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="TO"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="OTHER"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

where DATETIME should serialize to `System.DateTime` and the DATETIMEqual is not needed at all (the service suggests defaulting to "Other").

I had a thought of possibly using a dictionary for passing around serialization information, but this seems like it would complicate maintenance and extension, though would be better (possibly) then individualized serializers.

So, my question. Is there a relatively maintainable way of accomplishing custom serialization of custom classes, or is it better to use built in serializers? While I know the response will generally be "premature optimization" but is there performance cost that can be avoided using custom serialization? While my bigger bottleneck will be API calls, if we can shave off a reasonable amount of time in serialization, that would reduce cost (using AWS Lambda).

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: XML Serialization is slow.  I prefer to use Xml Linq (XDocument).  The advantage of using Xml Serialization is the use of a schema that will automatically generate the c# classes and the error checking that is performed.

Comment: @jdweng That was the direction I was looking at. I was getting stuck with trying to generalize the process. Create a serialization/deserialization process that can take any class as input, because I am dealing with multiple classes, pretty much one for each service.

Comment: A generic method would require using foundation to enumerate through the properties of a class.  Other people have to be able to read the xml and may not be using same tools that you are using.  That is why creating a schema and working from the schema is the standard way of working.

Comment: @jdweng understood. Using schema obviously has its use case. I just don't think its particularly helpful in my case, as it adds a lot of bloat and large classes, with many of the properties not needed. I wasn't sure if custom attributes could elevate some of the maintenance burden by generalizing xml generation from custom classes, or if that would just add further headaches down the line. Or if there are other ways of generalizing the xml generation that may be helpful. Otherwise, I will have to go with my first option and create individual methods for xml generation.

Comment: Xml is usually jagged that the number and types of properties are not the same for each method.  So you still have to build a model to drive your customizer. The amount of work to build a model is the same as building the schema.

Comment: @jdweng I realized I may not have added additional pertinent information. The service I am trying to access use SOAP message requests/responses. I need to be able to work with concrete classes (or work with the response data in some way), so I need to marshal and unmarshal the data. I'm not sure if you are suggesting building my own internal schema or if your referring to the external schema. Perhaps I still haven't provided the right information. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: A schema may already exist and URL of schema is in the XML. Check XML for any schemas.  You can use the xsd.exe tool to automatically generate the classes.

Comment: This is actually part of the problem. A relatively small XSD file generates 6000 lines of code (there is whitespace, but there is a lot of bloat too), with many nested objects that complicates working with the class as is. The names of the elements in the XSDs are often cryptic, complex or unclear. I do not need several properties of these classes and wanted to make it more straight forward to work with, then generate XML to meet the contract. That was the idea at least. Some of these XSDs generate 20,000+ lines with hundreds of properties and multilayer nested objects.

Comment: Its also not necessarily the class size that's the problem, though I think this will impact its use in AWS. Its also interfacing with the class. Just seem overly complicated and I wanted to make that less so.